# How would I go about recovering access to my TrueCrypt Volume?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, password-recovery

I forgot my password of a TrueCrypt file I used a few years ago.

How would I go about 'cracking' it? I'm not sure if there is a way to attack it or if it can only be done by brute-force. I used it on a Mac. I still have the Mac I used it on, but of course turned that off many times since I used it.

I have a passphrase that I thought would relate to this file. Maybe I used some variant of it. But might be something completely different. I have some other words that I might have used, but would need give it another thought how I could have used those.

**Is there an automated way to test variations on what I think the passphrase was to regain access to the volume? Is there any other way I might regain access?**

Comment: Welcome to Super User Zjost! I have edited your question, as Super User is not a password-cracking service. If you feel it could be further improved, please feel free to [edit it further](https://superuser.com/posts/1301421/edit) :)

Comment: Also, cash bounties isn't the way we do these things.

Comment: OK. Sorry for that! Thanks for rephrasing! If anyone has some advise ... would be great.

Comment: @bertieb - possible to put it back to 'active' status ?

Comment: There's programs that can guess (or help create wordlists for guessing) passphrases, didn't you google first?

Comment: @Xen2050 if you have strategy which involves passphrases for a truecrypt volume based on suggestions, that sound like an answer :)

Comment: The basics should be generate a list of possible words (search a repo for "generat word list") hopefully using what you remember, then throw the list at a program to try them (cryptsetup can open some tcrypt containers), using a bash script & checking the status should even work. @bertieb I would, but don't have all the details, and don't really want to get put on any "lists" myself ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I think I found some applications that might help with brute-force using some possible passphrases that I might have used. 'Unfortunately' I never use normal nor short phrases, so will be a hard nut to crack.  I hoped there would be a real flaw in Truecrypt that could be exploited, as that was the news in 2014. But doesn't really look like it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is a program called `hashcat`.

Take a look on its website: https://hashcat.net/hashcat/

It should be possible to try dictionary attack which you will build in a text file and then try all the given passwords, or you may want to brute-force the password by trying all the combinations from given characters.